# How to retain appended field data jquery

Tags: jquery, html, database, theory

I have a piece of code that appends fields to a form as demonstrated in the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renierdebruyn/t5LYw/13/).

Is there a way to retain the **appended** fields after form submission, when a user comes back to the page?  I am not asking for code, I am asking if it is possible, and in theory how?

**UPDATE:**

The data that was in the appended fields is saved to a database, would I then run an `if` statement to check if there is data for that user then call the append function to create the fields again? Or would it be better to pre-create hidden fields and then just clone, change the type and fill them with data?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Make some flag to check the page call from after form submission, if so call the add the field add button click.

Comment: So if there is, lets say 10 entries in the db(containing data from the `appended` fields) I would run an `if` to check if there is data in the db for that specific user and then call the `append` function to create the fields again?

Comment: Its based on your requirement. Am just tell possibility for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already saved all the needed data to your database, i would create the form without the hidden fields. Then when the user clicks a button/link to add additional fields you could send an ajax request fetching the correct data for the additional fields. when the ajax request returns some json/xml/... you can just add the fetched data to your form.

Comment: I like the ajax idea. Let me know if I understand you correctly? You are saying that I only call the data from the database and create the input elements when the user clicks the button to add more input elements?

Comment: Good idea, but I need the input fields to display on page load, as the user needs to know what is in the database already, not just when they click on the `add` button, as the user needs to make a decisions on the data that they previously submitted to the database. Any ideas?

Comment: since you already serve the page from the server you can generate everything that you want on load there. Once they need to fill in new input fields you send a new request to fetch the needed data